# WPF and MVVM question regarding usage of UI element function

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am trying to move an already existing application towards the MVVM pattern but it's not easy. How do people solve issues where they have to call methods on UI methods when for instance calculating complex properties.

For instance if I have a Canvas and want to access PointFromScreen method, or handing a Viewport element? Do you have to create a derived class?

Comment: Maybe you should add a sample of your code where you have questions about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would think about when rewriting those methods is, if they are UI specific or manipulating data.
If your `PointFromScreen` method is UI specific, you wouldn't have to move it into MVVM at all and instead keep it as is.

If it is however changing the underlying Model you would have to make a new Command (deriving `ICommand`) and pass the attributes through the `CommandProperties`in XAML.

Hope this helps a little?

Comment: So in this instance I need to update the position of canvas objects. So the objects position could be bound to a property in the VM but the property relies on getting Canvas.PointFromScreen

Comment: Maybe you could use the `MouseDown` event for that:
[get the position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12778353/8649015)
[bind the event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47199796/8649015)

Comment: Unfortunately it is done programmatically and not based on mouseclick, nevertheless the event would still need to call PointToScreen on the Canvas object, I think.

Comment: So this is coming from the model then? When it's coming from the code? 
In that case it should affect the ViewModel, which is then firing the OnPropertyChanged. You will probably have to make some properties in your viewmodel for that, sry. I think this is basically as far as I can help with this one (as long as I don't know what exactly PointFromScreen is doing here and how the code will be executed etc.)